# Align each UICollectionCell differently

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build a chat app and for presenting the chat view (`ChatVC`) I use `UICollectionView`.

You probably know that in chat apps the sent messages are aligned to the right and the received messages are aligned to the left.

My question is how do I set the alignment/inset of each cell based on its type (send/received) in the `UICollectionView`?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this repo and try diving in the code to understand the concept message kit https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit

Comment: @Florian_L I don't want to use a 3rd party extension. I want to build it with my own `UICollectionView`. Any idea?

Comment: hmmm so check that playlist you can find some good resources I think https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtEoKixIfG4&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JHGoEg41IJNk9QQ_hPWcyRo

Comment: @Florian_L I've already watched it. He uses a different way than I do and it seems really messy. I'm looking for a different way (just to align/change the inset)

Comment: To be able to align messages this way you should build your own `UICollectionViewLayout`

Comment: @iWheelBuy OK. But how? What should I add in the subclass?

Comment: @FS.O6 it's a good question. It will contain the logic which calculates positions of cells and some other code related to `UICollectionViewLayout`. I advice to start with some `UICollectionViewLayout` tutorial which is not related to a messenger layout, but just shows the basic approach how to build any custom layout. For example: http://samwize.com/2017/03/26/guide-to-uicollectionview-with-custom-layout/

Comment: @iWheelBuy I've read it. Thanks. But I still don't understand how can I achieve an alignment. Can you please help me with a more specific answer? Thank you!

Comment: @FS.O6 it will take a lot of time to help with a specific answer, that is why I'm not able to help. So you have to choose - use some framework (like **MessageKit**) or spend a lot of time understanding. It took me some months to understand `UICollectionViewLayout` and I ended with my personal layout **SquareMosaicLayout** but it won't suit your needs. I can advice **Chatto** by **Badoo**

Comment: @iWheelBuy I don't want to use a 3rd party framework because the design of my app is a bit different than the design of the 3rd party (my app doesn't have chat bubbles, it has chat squares). That why I think I have to do it myself. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FS.O6 You are 100% right, but it will take a lot of time. Btw, you can use `UITableView` with two types of cells: left-alligned and right-alligned. That is how I do a chat app atm.